# Non EU student(Indian), studying at German university,planning to do an internship in Netherlands company

Tags: immigration, eu, schengen, internship

I am a non EU student living and studying in Germany. I am looking at internships(for 6 months) in Netherlands and I was wondering the immigration procedures involved for me?

Thank you.

Comment: I am another non-EU student who living and studying in Turkey. I'm also an Turkey citizen. I got an internship from the Netherlands company, but don't know the procedure of the immigration. Did you find anything about procedure?